# Is it natural to use the verb "shift" in the sense of changing a date?

Tags: word-usage

Is it natural to use the verb in the following sentence?

> The party is on July the 1st, but I would like to **shift** it to July the 2nd.

If it is perfectly natural than is the preposition *to* fine after *shift* or for would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the sentence you are asking about seems fine and is perfectly idiomatic.

When we speak about something moving, this is often accompanied by a direction or the new location (eg "I am moving *to* Florida"). In your example, the subject is the party, and the party is moving (or shifting) *to* a new date.

The only thing about your sentence that I may consider changing would be:

> The party is *currently scheduled for* July the 1st, but I would like to shift it to July the 2nd.

OR

> The party *was* on July the 1st, but I would like to shift it to July the 2nd.

This is because, if the party is changing to a new date, it seems incorrect to say that it *is* on the old date. My first example would be what I would say if the change was tentative and subject to approval; the second would be what I would say if the original date was not possible in any case.